# Throwing errors with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, socket.io

I've created an Express app (with Angular) that uses socket.io for real-time communication. How can I return an error from the server to the client within the `socket.on()` function?

Here's my code:

```
io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
    socket.on('create game', () => {
        if(condition) {
            // Want to throw error here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a built-in event that socket.io already provides called **Connect_failed**

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_error_handling.htm) you have more information about Error Handling if you need it, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I already saw the page before, but wasn't sure how to send the error. The way I understand it, the function is for the client side and catches errors, but the page doesn't say anything about how to send them.